# Projected Entangled Pair States (PEPS) and classical statistical physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-entanglement, tensor-network

In the paper [arXiv:quant-ph/0601075](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0601075) the authors introduce an interesting correspondence between Projected Entangled Pair States (PEPS) and classical statistical physics. Basically, for any locally-interacting classical statistical system with partition function
$$Z=\sum_{\{\sigma\}} e^{-\beta E[\{\sigma\}]},$$
where $\{\sigma\}$ collectively label the classical spin configuration, we can associate a PEPS state
$$|\psi\rangle=\sum_{\{\sigma\}} e^{-\frac{\beta}{2} E[\{\sigma\}]}|\{\sigma\}\rangle,$$
such that $Z=\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$, and there is an exact mapping between thermal expectation values and quantum expectation values, e.g.
$$\langle\sigma_j\rangle_{\beta}=\langle\psi|\hat{\sigma}^z_j|\psi\rangle/\langle\psi|\psi\rangle.$$
[Note that $|\psi\rangle$ can be easily shown to be a PEPS since $e^{-\frac{\beta}{2} E[\{\sigma\}]}$ is a product of local Boltzmann weights.]

So every locally-interacting classical statistical system can be mapped to a PEPS. I want to know under what condition is the reverse direction true, i.e. **which family of PEPS can be mapped to a classical statistical system in the above way?** It is clear that if the local PEPS tensor takes only non-negative values, then $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$ can be interpreted as a classical partition function with strictly local interactions. But this is not a necessary condition-- even if the local tensor takes negative values sometimes, it is possible that it becomes completely positive after doing a suitable gauge transformation.

[one motivation to ask this question is that, as we know, local properties of a general PEPS can not be calculated as easily as MPS in 1D; yet if we know an exact correspondence to a statistical model, its properties can be more easily understood from that classical model, e.g. by doing Monte-Carlo simulations]